# How to decrypt PKCS7 bouncycastle in java

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I have message encrypt by PKCS7 Asymmetric encryption method. inside have xml

I have tried to decrypt by this below

```
public static byte[] decryptData(byte[] encryptedData, PrivateKey decryptionKey) throws CMSException {

    byte[] decryptedData = null;
    if (null != encryptedData && null != decryptionKey) {
        CMSEnvelopedData envelopedData = new CMSEnvelopedData(encryptedData);

        Collection<RecipientInformation> recipients = envelopedData.getRecipientInfos().getRecipients();
        KeyTransRecipientInformation recipientInfo = (KeyTransRecipientInformation) recipients.iterator().next();
        JceKeyTransRecipient recipient = new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(decryptionKey);

        return recipientInfo.getContent(recipient);
    }
    return decryptedData;
}
```

its error malformed content when

```
CMSEnvelopedData envelopedData = new CMSEnvelopedData(encryptedData);
```

Comment: Without seeing the bytes of `encryptedData` it is impossible to help you.

Comment: If you have (or get) OpenSSL and have (or put) the PKCS7 bytes in a file, try `openssl asn1parse -in file -inform {der|pem}` which should give details, and if there is a problem, a more specific error. Choose der or pem depending on which the data is. Also, do you know how the encrypted message was created e.g. what program(s)/command(s)?